# How do I control individual pixels outside of a frame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I need a way to control individual pixels on a monitor that are not inside a frame. Is there any way I can directly change a pixel at a certain x,y to a certain colour?

Comment: If it's contained inside a java window, then yes.  Outside one, you won't be able to without JNI and some external code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Java's "Full-Screen Exclusive Mode" API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html

In this example:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/examples/CapabilitiesTest.java

You see a Java application acquiring the "ContentPane" container from the graphics device, then it creates a JPanel and adds it to content pane.  Once you do that, you're free to override the paintComponent of the JPanel with something like this:

```
 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
 }
```

You can of course set whatever you draw to any color, and you can draw something other than a rectangle too.

The drawback is, you don't get transparency, in case you're looking to draw ONLY that pixel and leave the rest of the screen preserved.  This StackOverflow question investigates this issue further: [java fullscreen window with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362210/java-fullscreen-window-with-transparency)